# Find the best polynomial approximation of the piecewise function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the best approximation of the function

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
1 - x \quad\text{ for  } 0 \le x \le 1 \\
1 + x \quad\text{ for  } -1 \le x \le 0 \\
\end{cases}$$

in the interval $[-1,~ 1]$ by a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $\le 4$, meaning that the integral

$$\int_{-1}^{1} (|f(x) - p(x)|)^2\,{\rm d}x $$ is minimal possible.

We know that the best approximation is unque and coinced with the orthogonal projection. The minimal distance is equal to to length of orthogonal projection of $x$ into ${\rm ort}_{U}x$.

Answer (score 4):

Given a function $f\in L^2[-1,1]$, the polynomial of degree $d$ (in your case $d=4$) minimizing that quantity is

$\sum_{k=0}^d \alpha_k P_k(x)$

Where:

- $P_k(x)=\frac{1}{2^kk!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}[(x^2-1)^k]$, also known as the k-th Legendre polynomial. It's a suitable multiple of the k-th derivative of $(x^2-1)^k$, and it has degree exactly $k$. Legendre polynomials are a complete orthogonal system fro $L^2[-1,1]$; they are not orthonormal, since $\|P_k\|_2=\sqrt{\frac{2}{2k+1}}$.
- $\alpha_k=\frac{2k+1}{2}\int_{-1}^1f(x)P_k(x)dx$

Wikipedia provides $P_k(x)$ for $k=0,\ldots,10$, you need the first 5 of them:

$$P_0(x)=1\\P_1(x)=x\\P_2(x)=\frac{3x^2-1}{2}\\P_3(x)=\frac{5x^3-3x}{2}\\P_4(x)=\frac{35x^4-30x^2+3}{8}$$

The rest is a calculation.

Comment: I liked your solution.Thank you!I am sorry but I don't think I know how to proceed from here, if you could give me a hint. @G.Sassatelli

Comment: How do I get the best approximation?? @G.Sassatelli

Comment: Sorry, I was offline.

First, you calc the coefficients $\alpha_k,\ k=0,1,2,3,4$ through the formula.

Then, you calc the minimal distance, that is

$$\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1\left|f(x)-\sum_{k=0}^4\alpha_kP_k(x)\right|^2dx}\\$$

It's a very general approach, though it requires many calcs.

Comment: You should get
$$p(x)=\frac{1}{2}P_0(x)-\frac{5}{8}P_2(x)+\frac{9}{48}P_4(x)=\frac{105}{128}x^4-\frac{105}{64}x^2+\frac{113}{128}$$

Hence, by the above formula, the minimal distance should be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{384}}$
@DI...

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Er}{{\rm Error}}$

Define the problem and solve the differential calculus:

$$\begin{align}
%
\Er(A, B, C, D, E)
%
   &= \int_{-1}^{1} (Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E - f(x))^2 ~dx
%
\\ \\ &= \int_{-1}^{0} (Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E - 1 - x)^2 ~dx \\
   \\ &+  \int_{0}^{1}  (Ax^4 + Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E - 1 + x)^2 ~dx 
%
\\ \\ &=  \frac{2\,{A}^{2}}{9}  +  \frac{2\,{B}^{2}}{7}  +  \frac{2\,{C}^{2}}{5}  +  \frac{2\,{D}^{2}}{3}  +  \frac{2\,{E}^{2}}{1}
   \\ &-  \frac{2\,A}{15}  -  \frac{C}{3}  -  2\,E
   \\ &+  \frac{4\,A\,E}{5}  +  \frac{4\,C\,E}{3}  +  \frac{4\,B\,D}{5}  +  \frac{4\,A\,C}{7}  +  \frac{2}{3}
% 
\end{align}$$

Solve the system of 5 linear equations :

$$\frac{\partial~\Er }{\partial~ A} = 
\frac{\partial~\Er }{\partial~ B} =  
\frac{\partial~\Er }{\partial~ C} =  
\frac{\partial~\Er }{\partial~ D} =  
\frac{\partial~\Er }{\partial~ E} = 0
$$

To get:

$$A=\frac{105}{128} ,~ B=0 ,~ C=-\frac{105}{64} ,~ D=0 ,~ E=\frac{113}{128} $$

[image]

$$\Er\left(\frac{105}{128} ,~ 0 ,~ -\frac{105}{64} ,~ 0 ,~ \frac{113}{128} \right) = \frac{1}{384}$$